# Set Up CORS IIS7

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iis-7, cors

I have a webforms site and I am trying to make a web request via JQuery to a page on the same site. However the page I am trying to access is on HTTPS rather than the HTTP that the page the Jquery is executed from uses. I get an error regarding "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" so I looked into it and I now have the following added to my web.config.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

And this is my JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
            url: "https://www.example.com",
            success: function (resp) {
                //register browser as supported
                console.log("supported");
            },
            error:function(e){
                //register browser as unsupported
                console.log(e);
                console.log("unsupported");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

However I now get the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Try adding `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` too. Also, you can remove the `headers` property from your jQuery AJAX call; the header is redundant in a request.

Comment: I have now added <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET" /> but it does not fix the error. However Removing the header from the ajax request gives me back the original error of "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access."

Comment: Your configuration seems fine, yet does not seem to be applied to the response. You can check the headers in the 'network' tab of the console to confirm this. All I can suggest is that you double check that you're not overriding the headers in the web.config of your website itself.

Comment: @coolblue2000 can you post your webconfig?

Answer (score 0):

I have realised what was happening. We have a strange setup where there is a CMS system that is the root site but the rest of the system is its own webforms application. The CMS systems web.config gets called first so that is where the changes needed to be made but I had made them in the main sites web.config.

Silly setup....

Thanks for the help.